# Javascript Error when embedding Plotly html into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I'm trying to embed HTML from plotly into a Jupyter notebook.  This is the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="7979e646-13e6-4f44-8d32-d8effc3816df" style="height: 525; width: 100%;" class="plotly-graph-div"></div><script type="text/javascript">window.PLOTLYENV=window.PLOTLYENV || {};window.PLOTLYENV.BASE_URL="https://plot.ly";Plotly.newPlot("7979e646-13e6-4f44-8d32-d8effc3816df", [{"x": [1, 2, 3], "y": [3, 1, 6]}], {}, {"showLink": false, "linkText": ""})</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I put this in a regular HTML file and open it in a browser, it works just fine.  On the other hand, if I put it in an `%%html` cell in Jupyter or if I use `display(HTML(html_string))` from `IPython.display` module, I get this error:

```
Javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: I tried `from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode; init_notebook_mode()` at the top of the notebook, just to load the necessary JS. It got me past your error, but then failed with `Javascript error adding output! TypeError: Argument not optional` while it was starting to render the graph.